# Extend built-in django {% include %} tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use a custom `include` like this:

```
<script>{% custom_include 'bundle.js' %}</script>

def custom_include:
  if settings.env == 'test'
    return ''

  return include('bundle.js')
```

Can I import it from somewhere?

Comment: check out template tags on django docs

Comment: I would suggest to look into Static files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/. You can make specific conditions in the settings.py file when you work in the local env. I think that is what you are trying to do right?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no info on using built-in tags inside custom

Comment: I need to include a static file depending on environment var. E.g. if it's `test` - return nothing, otherwise use built-in include